# How to call a variadic function in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

How to call a function with variable number of arguments from JavaScript, defined eg. like this?

```
setIntValues(int... values)
```

(the example is from `android.animation.ObjectAnimator` object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the arguments as an array:

```
obj.setIntValues([0,5]);
```

For defining a type, in overloaded functions you can use:

```
var arr = Array.create("int",2);
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 5;
obj.setIntValues(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using javascript:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
setIntValues.apply(undefined, arr);
```

if you're using typescript:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
setIntValues(...arr);
```